# Fingerprint functionality to confirm payment on any device

Tags: web-applications, fingerprint

I am building a web app and I would like to implement a fingerprint scanner on it.

The web app would have both a merchant account and a customer account which means a customer can confirm payments on the merchant's account.

I want to know if this functionality is possible.

Comment: Can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

For integrating the scanner to your web app, web api support is required. The answer to this web api, is discussed at [Is there any possible way to connect fingerprint biometric device to the website..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50795446/is-there-any-possible-way-to-connect-fingerprint-biometric-device-to-the-website/52383382#52383382). Hope this will help you better.