# Is there any possible way to connect fingerprint biometric device to the website..?

Tags: c#, angular, fingerprint, biometrics

Is there any possible way to connect fingerprint biometric device to the website..?

I have created a web-based ERP system. As per the client requirement, I need to integrate fingerprint logging system. My website was developed with C# and angular2.

I have tried many sdks but nothing works as I expected.

Comment: It depends on the hardware and its drivers. However, in case you are talking of a usb fingerprint scanner and if you have "control" over the users in terms of "they are all working in my company" you could also write a small desktop app and deploy it via click once (if applicable). That little app runs in the background could be a bridge between the fingerprint scanner and your website.

Comment: schandensbegrnzer thats not my case more employees are working in remote also... i cannot force them to install any desktop applicaton

Comment: If you have access to a DigitalPersona Fingerprint Scanner you can integrate it with your C#.NET website as is done in this ASP.NET Web Biometric Fingerprint Authentication Software Module pack https://jomutech.com/webfingerprintauthenticationaspnet.php Firstly, you will need to connect USB Fingerprint scanner to your Development Computer. Secondly, Call Biometric Fingerprint API in your ASP.NET code to Enrol Fingerprints on Website and to do Fingerprint Authentication in your Website. It can be done and it has been done before. What is it in particular that you are struggling with?

Comment: @JomutechByte according to my client requirement "they can use any fingerprint device". so now am looking for something like WEBUSB

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805697/integrating-biometric-fingerprint-to-php-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fingerprint scanners with Web API for interacting from the web page is not provided by the manufacturers. There are some 3rd party vendors providing the APIs for the same under payable license. You may check their websites to find out if they are suitable for you. Few i could remember are [CamsUnit](http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html), [NeuroTechnology](https://www.neurotechnology.com/prices-verifinger.tml), [Jmutech](https://jomutech.com/html5webbiometricfingermodule.php).

Answer (score 2):

The only way it could have worked is with a PWA, but according to [this blog](https://insanelab.com/blog/web-development/progressive-web-apps-pwa-vs-native/) :

> PWAs have limited capabilities when it comes to offering integration with a smartphone or tablet’s hardware features such as NFC and Bluetooth functionality as well as the device’s sensor package (accelerometer, fingerprint sensor, etc.). This prevents PWAs from being developed for use with mobile accessories and “wearables” like smart watches, fitness trackers and wireless earphones.

Maybe you should turn your look to Ionic and Cordova, which can access hardware.

Comment: The first sentence is misleading. PWA in this context is just a web-site that leverages browser offered APIs to perform certain tasks. So as long as web APIs do not offer access biometric auth capabilities on users device - nor web-site not PWA can offer such access. But indeed hybrid app using cordova can narrow this gap using a plugin like this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio/

Comment: Not in the case of android : PWAs have access to many hardware features, such as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504194/4676340)